# how to add/edit parameters for a startup service (/etc/init.d/)

Tags: upstart, services, customization, pure-ftpd

I have installed pure-ftp server but i had problems logging into it with virtual users.
I managed to diagnose the problem: it's the incomplete default parameter specification. This is how the script starts by default at startup:

`Starting ftp server: Running: /usr/sbin/pure-ftpd -l pam -u 1000 -8 UTF-8 -E -O clf:/var/log/pure-ftpd/transfer.log -B`

but that's not good because -l is not specified. This is the correct form to start it:

`pure-ftpd -l puredb:/etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.pdb`

So, the q is: **How to change the startup param definition for pure-ftpd?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most services allow you to change startup params in `/etc/default/NAME`. If not, you'll have to edit `/etc/init.d/NAME` (or `/etc/init/NAME.conf` for Upstart scripts). Do not forget to restart the service, that's not automatically done for you.

Comment: These are the file that could be found in the dirs, http://pastebin.com/8Fj2Peya and http://pastebin.com/2TFZVfpN , but i couldn't find anything useful to change. Could you take a look please?

Comment: Have a look at `/usr/sbin/pure-ftpd-wrapper`

Comment: Searched for it but with no results, please have a look too : http://pastebin.com/LvXv6yfQ

Comment: From `man pure-ftpd-wrapper`: *The Pure-FTPd daemon allows to use different authentication methods together. The authentication methods are tried in the order they are specified on the command line. In order to achieve the same flexibility with files in the /etc/pure-ftpd directory, pure-ftpd-wrapper checks all valid symbolic links within the directory /etc/pure-ftpd/auth in alphabetical order. E.g., a link in this directory pointing to /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/PureDB would enable authentication against a PureDB database.*; try: `sudo ln -s ../conf/PureDB /etc/pure-ftpd/auth/99puredb`